# Loading an image from a folder using OpenCV 3.0 in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, opencv3.0

I am using Visual Studio 2010, with OpenCV 3.0. I'm trying to load some images from a folder but I am having problems.

Firstly I did not have the file dirent.h, so I downloaded it in order to get the DIR* and "dirent*" structures to access to the files. All seems to be well, but now when I get to the line

> string fileName = in_file->d_name;

I have found that I don't access to the name of the file.

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <opencv2/core/dirent.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <io.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")

#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::ml;
using namespace std;

int patchWidth = 15;
int patchHeight = 15;


int main(int, char**)
{
    string imagesPath = "Images";
    string resultsPath = "Patches";

            DIR* FD;
            struct dirent* in_file;

            if (NULL == (FD = opendir (imagesPath.c_str())))
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error : Failed to open input directory\n");
                return 0;
            }

            while ((in_file = readdir(FD)))
            {
                    /* On linux/Unix we don't want current and parent directories
                     * If you're on Windows machine remove this two lines
                     */
              //      if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, "."))
              //          continue;
              //      if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, ".."))
              //          continue;

                    /* Open directory entry file for common operation */
                    /* TODO : change permissions to meet your need! */

                    string fileName = in_file->d_name;

                    string pathFile = imagesPath;
                    pathFile.append("/");
                    pathFile.append(fileName);
                    //pathFile.append(".jpg");
                    Mat img = imread(pathFile.c_str());
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

for a much simpler solution, just use [cv::glob](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gaf91b7f383218e2d3f760939140942297) :

```
String imagesPath = "Images/*.png"; // it has filters, too !

vector<String> fn;
glob(path, fn, true); // recursive, if you want
for (size_t i=0; i<fn.size(); i++)
{
   Mat img = imread(fn[i]);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Not only is this simpler, but it avoids the need for the platform-specific lines that are commented out in the OP.

Comment: @berak I tried your suggestion but even enters the loop "for". I understand that "path" is really "imagesPath", no?

Comment: @JoseleMG "path" is a folder with optional filter for image types, like *.jpg, if you use a filter, it will also ignore (pesky) hidden things like 'thumbs.db' on windows

Comment: @berak Thank you very much for your help! In the end I have loaded the images!

Comment: @berak I have another question: How could I create a folder from the code where saving the images depending on his frame? For example, I want to create automatically the folder "Frame1", the folder "Frame2" and saving the images in real time.